# CSS can't seem to set height to 100% of parent container

Tags: css

I'm wondering why the height: 100% on the li's in this does not set the height to the ul they're a child of.

http://homecoming.umd.edu/index2.html

?_?

Answer (score 2):

You need to set an explicit non-percentage height on a parent element. You currently have `height:100%` on your `<ul>`, too, which you'll notice isn't doing anything. If it were working, your navigation would expand your whole page, because its parent is your wrapper div that contains a bunch of other stuff. However, if you set your `<ul>` to something like `height:40px`, the `<li>` will follow suit.

`height:100%` depends on an explicit height set somewhere in a parent element. If no height is ever set with anything other than percentages (or if every parent element all the way up to `<body>` and `<html>` doesn't have `height:100%` set), then it will never actually do anything, because it has no reference height to start from.

Comment: Also, setting `height:100%` on your `ul` is probably a bad idea when you want it to be a menu at the top of the page and its parent is the container div for the entire page. That's like saying you want your menu to take up the whole page. You'll want to put an actual height to it.

Comment: Hmm... I was kinda hoping the height would be explicitly set by the height of the container. Like, in the event we ever needed a 100 word title for some godforsaken reason, it'd automatically do it. Your explanation makes sense though, so I suppose it's what I'll have to do ;_;

Comment: When your navigation's container is the wrapper div for all of the content, where is the browser supposed to get the height you want? If you've found an answer that works for you, don't forget to mark it as accepted (using the checkmark next to the answer).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what other people are getting, but using FF4 with Firebug I can see that there is no `height: 100%;` for the li's. There is for the ul however and that seems to be working fine.

Maybe trying putting `height: 100%;` in your css file for `#nav li`. Also, there's a padding in there that may throw you off in the future. Be sure to look into that if it's giving you problems.

EDIT: This is what I'm seeing in Firebug for the `#nav li`:

```
#nav li {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    width: 9.09%;
}
```

No mention of the height attribute.

Comment: Yeah, I'm sorry - I was adding that via the Chrome inspector. But it doesn't work regardless of whether it's in the file or not (it is now). Once I can figure this out, I'll work on the padding issues x.x

Comment: So, I was playing around and noticed that if you used `display:inline-block;` instead of `float:left;` it plays a bit nicer with the height. However, it presents some other design flaws. Maybe you can find a way to fix them though.

Comment: Well, unfortunately with that it still doesn't set the li to the proper height, it just changes the position within the stylized ul to look a little better.

Comment: Yep, you're right. Sorry bout that. I'm not sure how to go about fixing it. My suggestion would be to use tables, if possible

Comment: There's no need for tables (besides, tables are the semantically wrong choice here), just a better understanding of how `height:100%` actually works.

Answer (score 0):

This would fix it (it won't fix the overlap in 'Greek organizations' though)

```
#nav { height: 44px; }
#nav a { height: 30px; }
```

Comment: I mean, I thought of that, but at the same time, I'd like this code to be automatic and portable and happy and fun, etc.

Answer (score 0):

> I was kinda hoping the height would
>   be explicitly set by the height of the
>   container. Like, in the event we ever
>   needed a 100 word title for some
>   godforsaken reason, it'd automatically
>   do it.

If I'm understanding this correctly and this is the real reason you are asking this question, just set #nav to "height:auto;" and, if you want it to be at least a certain height use something like "min-height:44px;"

Answer (score -1):

Height of 100% in CSS can be tricky sometimes, as it depends on the size of the parent containers.  [Here are some similar questions/answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Css%20100%25) that might help.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't seem to find anything too useful there. Most of the people asking this question weren't actually using height: 100%;.